# Razor Page Display Template for SSN stored as a Varchar(9)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, display-templates

I am trying to display SSN stored as Varchar(9) with dashes.

The SSN in the database is stored as a varchar(9), with no dashes. It is not stored as a numeric because any leading zeros are dropped if it is stored as a numeric. I cannot use the DisplayFormat attribute with  DataFormatString = "{0:###-##-####}" because that seems to only work if SSN is stored as a Long type. So, I am trying to create a Display Template for it. I have created a .cshtml file called SSN and placed it in a folder called DisplayTemplates inside the Shared folder, and I am using @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SSN) on the Razor Pages to display the SSN, but the mask that I created in the display template does not take effect.

Here is the code in the SSN.cshtml display template:

```
@model PFDTrustDomain.Client

<div>
    @Model.SSN.Insert(2, "-").Insert(5, "-");
</div>
```

I expect the SSN to display like: 123-45-6789, but is continues to display like: 123456789.

Comment: It should be `.Insert(3, "-").Insert(6, "-")`, but otherwise it looks okay. I think. Can you put a breakpoint on that line and verify that the display template is actually being used?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was able to put a break point on the line and it would seem that the model is not getting hit at all. I am using @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SSN) to display the SSN on the page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the display template is not getting hit at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the issue (with the sage help of my mentor). In addition to changing the character positions to 3 and 6, as recommended by madreflection, it was necessary to add the string "Name of display template" into the DisplayFor method in the .cshtml file, like so:

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SSN, "SSN")
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

For display template is not getting hit, you need to copy the template to output folder by setting `Copy to Output Directory`.

Follow steps below:

1. `@Html.DisplayFor` and `@model PFDTrustDomain.Client` are mismatch, template expected Client, but you pass string with SSN. Change `@Html.DisplayFor` like `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SSN,"SSN")`
2. Change `@model PFDTrustDomain.Client` in template to below

   ```
   @model string

   <div>
       @Model.Insert(3, "-").Insert(6, "-");
   </div>
   ```
3. Set `Copy to Output Directory` for `Shared/DisplayTemplates/SSN.cshtml` to `Copy always`